# How do I vertically align a horizontal list that contains headings and icon images?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal navigation bar where each menu option has the heading with an icon underneath. When you hover over each option, the background color of that block will change and it will increase slightly in size. I have sized everything using percentages. It was all working up until I had to vertically align the menu options. The list height was 100% of the navigation bar. In order to vertically align each option I changed the display to table/table-cell instead of inline-block which worked, however there is now a thin space underneath the list, and each list item no longer occupies 100% of the navigation height ruining the hover background color effect.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZNEs.png) is a screenshot showing what the navigation bar looks like. I have made the list background pink to show the issue clearly but there would usually be no color leaving just the green background. The blue box hovering over the "learn" button should extend to the edges of the navigation bar like it did before I changed the display.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJaic.png) is a screenshot showing what it looks like when the li display is set to inline-block. This is pretty much exactly what I want except it's not vertically aligned.

This is a simplified version of my html (I took out titles and irrelevant details)

```
<nav class="nav_bar">
    <span id="logo">
        <a href="home.html"><img src="images/nav_bar/logo_img.png"></a>
        <a href="home.html"><img src="images/nav_bar/logo_text.png"></a>
    </span>
    <ul class="nav_menu">
        <li id="learn"><a href="learn.html">LEARN<br><img src="images/nav_bar/learn.png"></a></li
        ><li id="watch"><a href="watch.html">WATCH<br><img src="images/nav_bar/watch.png"></a></li
        ><li id="share"><a href="share.html">SHARE<br><img src="images/nav_bar/share.png"></a></li
        ><li id="more"><a href="more.html">MORE<br><img src="images/nav_bar/more.png"></a></li
        ><li id="active"><a href="home.html">HOME<br><img src="images/nav_bar/home.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my relevant css

```
.nav_menu {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 35%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav_menu img {
    width: 70%;
}
.nav_menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav_menu a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav_menu a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);  
}

#learn a:hover {
    background-color: #69D1ED;
}
```

I also briefly tried using the icons as list background images, but I had too much trouble positioning them underneath the text.

This is for an assignment, so I'm restricted to html and css only, and it must work for Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera.

Comment: did u try flexbox?

Comment: as in keep everything else the same but just get rid of the .nav_menu display and change .nav_menu li display to inline-flex and .nav_menu a display to flex? That's what I tried and it ended up moving the image to the right of the text and scaling it to 100% height unproportionally

Comment: I'm looking into flexbox now and it seems like it could work, but I can't seem to get it right. I made the changes mentioned in the previous comment which fixed the issues with the colored box and the thin space under the list. I got rid of vertically-aligned: middle and added content-align: center to .nav_menu a which worked the same. Then I added flex-wrap: wrap to stop the icon moving to the right. The only issues I'm having now is the icon scaling unproportionally (width is the same, height is 100% of the container) and contents aren't centered horizontally anymore.

Comment: justify-content: center fixed the horizontal alignment, almost there

Comment: Fixed the scaling issue by changing width to a vw value and putting the same vw for height. Thanks for the tip, everything works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
 
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
  transform: scale(1.1);  
}
 
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="tutorials"><a class="active" href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo is over here](https://jsfiddle.net/9bxoqcL3/31/)

Comment: This is similar to what I created, only mine is horizontal. But this doesn't address the issue I'm having as none of their menu options had images, were vertically aligned, or colored the whole bar on hover.